# Can't get HIGH_ACCURACY background locations in Android 8+

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-8.0-oreo

Android 8 only allows background location updates a few times per hour. This isn't a problem since I only request them about once an hour and only if the device isn't `STILL` and there arn't already passive updates doing the job. So maybe a few times a day. No detectable battery use on Android 7.

However, I do have an accuracy requirement and I discard locations with horizontal accuracy worse than about 1000 feet (Basically cell tower locations). The problem is that the network location comes almost instantly, and then the app is throttled and never receives the next update which might come from the GPS. Typically I would wait a minute to get a location with the desired accuarcy and then give up. On Android 8, even if I wait an hour I just get the network location every 20 minutes or so because of the throttling.

I can't find any LocationRequest setting for miniumum accuracy which would solve the problem entirely. `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` absolutley does NOT do this. It is only a "hint". `setSmallestDisplacement()` doesn't help because it doesn't affect the first update. Batching updates helps on rare occasions in my testing but not with any reliability.

Further, waiting in `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` for any length of time is not reasonable from a user perspective since the location indicator will be active on the device the whole time, even if the app is being throttled.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I could solve this problem? Perhaps Android does not intend for `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` to be used in the background at all, although I can find nothing about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need GPS, just use the GPS provider.  Don't screw around with the Criteria, request what you really need.

Comment: This could work as a fallback stratagy, but I don't want to limit to GPS provider generally. I just have an accuracy requirement which would ideally come from a wifi network, a "close" cell tower, or whatever other magic google does with the FusedProvider. I only want GPS to be included as well.

Comment: Falling back to GPS worked, but a little too well. Seems if you re-request from the GPS provider in the background you don't get throttled at all. I've opened a bug report. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72477437